# Simple PCRE Regex

Tags: regex, pcre

This would seem to be an easy question, but I'm struggling with greediness (I think), and I can't find an obvious example:

Given the following string:

```
text/html; text/xml; text/json
```

what do I do to retrieve the 'first subtype' ('html' in the above example)?

I've tried all sorts of combinations like this:

```
(.*)\/(.*)[ |;]
```

and trying to get the second variable.

I know that the string will always have at least one string in the form

```
aaa/bbb
```

and that may either be it, or it may be followed by a semi-colon (with possible whitespace between them) and more data (which I can ignore - I only need the first subtype). So the possible options could be like this:

```
text/html
text/html; text/xml
text/html ; text/xml     ; application/json
```

I had hoped it was as simple as looking for the first slash and then taking everything after that up to either a blank or a semi-colon or the end of the string (which is what I thought my regex was doing), but I'm not skilled enough in regex.

For clarification, this needs to be a PCRE-compatible regex, if that helps/hinders things...

Comment: `(.*?)\/(.*?)[ ;]` - use lazy matching. Or `[^\/]+\/(\S+)` (both with `preg_match` if it is for PHP)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do:

```
^[^\/]+\/([^\s;]+)
```

Now, `\1` is the first subtype you want.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mM8bS3/3)

Comment: `[^\s]` is just `\S`.

Comment: Hmm this regex will match `text/html;` with `"html;"`. Looks like you need `[^\s;]` :|